# How to create setup file in Visual studio 2012 professional?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating windows application in Visual Studio 2012 .I want create set up file of that application .But in visual Studio 2012 professional not provide options- Setup and deployment  What i can do for create setup file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inno Setup from http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php is a terrific tool.  Its free, but you can also donate if you want.

Comment: thanks .Can u told me steps. How to create my application setup file in Inno setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Install Shield or learn more about [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx)

Comment: Thanks .I have one query- Is it really Microsoft  remove setup and deployment option  from visual studio 2012